# How can I convert "rs2::video frame" to "CvCapture* "?

Tags: realsense

I'm newbie to the Intel Realsense SDK and coding in Visual Studio 2017(C or C++) for Intel Realsense camera D435.

In my example I have the following,

```
static rs2::frameset current_frameset;
auto color = current_frameset.get_color_frame();
frame = cvQueryFrame(color);
```

I've got an error on line 3 as ***"can not convert 'rs2::video_frame' to 'CvCapture'"***

I've not being able to find a solution to this issue and it's proving difficult and resulted in more errors.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it would be beneficial if you add more details to your question, link to source code if possible? Are you using https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense?

Comment: i'm sorry but there is not enough code. simply, i wish a function which convert rs2::video_frame to CvCapture.

Answer (score 0):

The cvQueryFrame accepts cvCapture instance, and it is used to retrieve the frame from camera. In LibRS, the frame you retrieved back can be used already, you don't have to get back it again. attached the snippet of CV example in LibRS, you can refer to the complete code [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/opencv/imshow)

```
rs2::pipeline pipe;
// Start streaming with default recommended configuration
pipe.start();

using namespace cv;
const auto window_name = "Display Image";
namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (waitKey(1) < 0 && cvGetWindowHandle(window_name))
{
    rs2::frameset data = pipe.wait_for_frames(); // Wait for next set of frames from the camera
    rs2::frame depth = color_map(data.get_depth_frame());

    // Query frame size (width and height)
    const int w = depth.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_width();
    const int h = depth.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_height();

    // Create OpenCV matrix of size (w,h) from the colorized depth data
    Mat image(Size(w, h), CV_8UC3, (void*)depth.get_data(), Mat::AUTO_STEP);

    // Update the window with new data
    imshow(window_name, image);
}
```